# Scale UI proportionally in a fixed position Unity C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C# and I am currently making a little useless game just to learn it.

My struggle now is to get the scale right for a level indicator. I have made a UI Image with the indicator background as a child of UI Panel inside of the Canvas. What I want is to scale the image proportionally while the position is being maintained in the bottom left corner of the view.

This is how I want it to scale.
If the view is wide, it would be like this, 200px x 200px.

[image]

If the view is narrower I want the image to be smaller, but with the same ratio. If the width of the narrow view is one third of the wide view, i want the image to be 67px x 67px. I do not want it to be scaled by the heigth of the view.

[image]

Does anyone know how this can be done?